# How to center a absolute div inside a fixed div

Tags: css

I have set up a modal for phots, so when i click on a small photo i get a larger photo up in a modal, the modal has `position: fixed;` and the modal-content has `position: absolute;` i can center it with `margin: auto; left: 0; right: 0;`but then the width goes all the way to the right and left, i want the modal content width to be the same as the photo inside it or the content of the modal-content

**my code:**

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding: 30px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */

}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}

.modalimg {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.modalimg  img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 

}
```

its maybe a bit messy now but i have tried alot of different things with no luck..

Comment: Hi can you provide  JSFiddle link or snipped code

Comment: You could use `transform:translate()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e5smw1s9/18/

Answer (score 9):

This is what I use when I center an absolute-positioned element, this works for me all the time:

```
.absolute-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here you are please

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  text..
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

to align absolute div to center
left: 0;
right: 0
text-align: center
this will align the div in center.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `text-align` won't work on an absolute-positioned element.

Comment: it works. as here width i can see 100%, I am assuming you want to center the inside element? If you want to center the div itself, you can reduce the width in percentage.https://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution that uses:

- `absolute` positioning on the content container (`.modal-content`)
- doesn't use `absolute|fixed` on the actual content

The content container (`.modal-content`) will grow along with its content. Finally, it's moved back to the middle using `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`:

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/u34g6ryq/)